# load report failed

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

Load report failed this error logged when i try to open Crystal report and if i restart my iis (iisreset) then it's working.

Here's my code:

```vb
Dim objReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass
Dim location As String = context.Server.MapPath("../POC/POC1.rpt")
objReport.FileName = location
objReport.Load()
objReport.SetDataSource(dsPOC)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I normally see this error message happeneing when there is a problem with the Reports Data Source. Have you tried to run the Report connection directly to the Database Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it will give you the perfect idea....

```
using System;using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;using CrystalDecisions.Shared;namespace Report
 {       public partial class Report : Document    
  {       public void ReportLoad()    
   {             ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();       
 string filePath = "C:\Projects\Application\Report\CrystalReport.rpt";            reportDocument.Load(filePath);  
          crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument; 
      }   
}}
```

Comment: zunna: Hi what is cyrstalreiportViewer is it object of any class . do i need to declare.

Comment: Yes. Its a Class and you don't need to declare that. You can get information from this Link.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665757%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: But i couldn't find any class like this at vb(my code behind file is vb)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. Now the problem solved by objReport.Dispose(). 
I called this Dispose Method after appending each document.  The problem might be i failed to release data form memory.

regards,
saj